# Json parse and add format

Tags: php, ajax, json

I use this in a function:

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'demopost.php',
     data: { ... },
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(data) 
     {
            console.log(data);
     }
  });
```

The demopost.php contains only a query.

The output will be:

[image]

But how can I show it inside a div? OR How can I add some formation e.g. with foreach like a php array?

EDIT:
I tried with it (the place of console.log(data):

```
$('.inner').append(data);
```

Of course there was a div with class inner. But nothing show

EDIT2:
The query in the demopost.php:

```
   ... try
        {
            $c_id = htmlspecialchars($_POST['cid']);
            $leftprice = $_POST['left'];
            $rightprice = $_POST['right'];
            $items=$main->pdo->prepare("SELECT name, price FROM clf_items WHERE category_id IN (
                SELECT node.id
                FROM clf_category AS node,
                clf_category AS parent
                WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt AND price BETWEEN :left AND :right
                AND parent.id = :c_id)");
            $items->execute(array(':c_id' => $c_id, ':left' => $leftprice, ':right' => $rightprice));
            $items_array = array(); 

            while ($row = $items->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                $items_array[] = $row; 
            }
        echo json_encode($items_array);exit;
        }...
```

Comment: you question is very confusing what you want to do actully can you please explain

Comment: means you want to show the output in the page from which you are firing the ajax. Right?

Comment: you can see an img from the console output but I want to put the output in a div and add some formating. e.g: Dell laptop - 105000 -new line- Toshiba....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing here is to return some JSON data from the server which can be read by javascript, but is not useful to be pushed into HTML without some processing.

One solution would be to get the JSON array you receive and transform it into a HTML string before pushing it onto the page. This might look like:

```
 success: function(data) 
 {
     var result = '<table>';
     for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
         result += '<tr><td>'+ data[i].name+'</td><td>'+data[i].price+'</td></tr>';
     }
     result+= '</table>';
     $(".inner").html(result);
 }
```

Now this has not money formatting, no html escaping, very crude layout etc pp. Before you try to make this raw sketch into something useful I recommend looking into the various template engines available for jQuery; a few are listed in this post: [jQuery Templates are deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911732/jquery-templates-are-deprecated) (and unlike the question suggests, jQuery templates are not dead, but got some competition).

However I would prefer another approach: create the HTML server side (instead of JSON), so you return a HTML snippet the same way you would return a full HTML page normally in PHP, and in the ajax request say you want HTML: `dataType: 'html',` and then you can push the result straight into `$(".inner").html(data)` (or `$(".inner").append(data)`, no idea how your HTML should look like), as you originally wanted.

I guess this is the same as schwierig wanted to say, but I feel one need to tell it more explicit.

Comment: It works now fine but you prefer/offer to use html dataType? So, now I changed the dataType to html instead of json and wrote the echo $items_array; instead of echo json_encode($items_array);exit; in the demopost.php but now it says "Notice: Array to string conversion in..." the print_r and var_dump is OK. How can I loop on it?

Comment: Of course just `echo $items_array` does not create html from it. Please check the php documentation how to write loops e.g. at http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php

Comment: I know loop in php and I can do it: foreach($items_array as $itemsarray){
  echo $itemsarray['name'];
  echo $itemsarray['price']; } in the demopost.php. But I do not want to do it in php file

Comment: Or if I use html dataType then I must to do it in the php file? (Cause I use Smarty I prefer to use every formating in .tpl like your post code in json format

Comment: If you do not want to create the html in php, then disregard my last sentence; this is just how I like to do it, doing as much as possible on the server. If you prefer to send json and do the html formatting in the browser, check out one of the javascript templating engines instead. Smarty seems to be a php template engine however, not sure why you cannot use it on the server side to create the html, to me it seems completely possible, but I have not tried.

Comment: Yep, that's basically what I wanted to say. Thanks for going more into detail, I wasn't really sure how detailed he wanted the answer (considering this is very basic Ajax).

Answer (score 1):

For what reason are you using Ajax if you are not processing the data you are sending? If you just want to format the data, you don't really need PHP to do that.

Of course it would be possible. If you want to process with PHP you need to echo your formatted result and use the `.done()` function as described in the jQuery API

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: this will run in the change event (jquery ui slider), so if it is changed the new query need to show the new result depending on the price

Comment: So you can process the id (or whatever else you are handing) in your PHP script and respond with the data you need to change your slider with.
To handle the response you need to use the `done´ function

Comment: I added: .done(function ( data ) {
 $('.inner').append(data);
 alert('ok');
}); but only the alert works

Comment: What did you echo in your PHP file? Can you add the code to your question?

Comment: added thequery from the demopost.php

Comment: Looks okay, try to use an id instead of a class on your dom object. Classes tend to return arrays in JS, it may be a problem.
And try to alert your data to check if the response is the right one.

If this doesn't help, I don't know :-/

Comment: still the alert works only. In this case: alert(data); The output is: [object Object],[object Object]

Comment: It works in this format: $('#inner').append("sample text"); :Confused

Comment: The class type assumes that you have more than one object on your page with the class `inner` that's why he is automatically creating an array with all objects that have the class `inner`, which in your case is only one.

Try to use the class type only when you really know that you will have multiple objects on your page.

Comment: Also as the data returned from the ajax call is a json array, I guess a loop over `data` and extract single fields from the elements would help, as just stuffing the JSON object into the html element will not produce any great results.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post('demopost.php',{..}, function(data) {
  $('.inner').html(data);
});
```

try this one hope it will help and make sure you have div with inner class