# Inserting HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok, I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220603/is-there-a-best-practice-for-generating-html-with-javascript) thread to figure out how to generate HTML with JavaScript. I attempted doing it with the following script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function generate_page() {
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var lines = 20;
    var output;
    while (x < lines) {
        while( y < lines*2){
            output = ("<div id='x" + x + "_" + y + "'>x</span>");
            $('board').prepend(output);
            y++;
        }
        y = 0;
        x++;
        $('board').append('<br />');
    }
}
</script>

</head>
<input type='button' value='test' onClick='generate_page()'>
<body>
<div id='board'>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

It doesn't return any errors but just simply doesn't do anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: a) you're using jQuery syntax so are you including jQuery and b) why is your input outside the body tag?

Comment: `$('board')` ==> `$('#board')`

Comment: The title of this post should be "Writing HTML with JavaScript"...

Comment: @ikaradashkov Why should it be called that?

Comment: @GerardSexton Because the title **used to be** "Inserting JavaScript in HTML". Now, I see that it has been modified to "Inserting HTML using JavaScript" which makes *total* sense (and is along the lines of what I had proposed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the # sign for the ids, try this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function generate_page() {
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var lines = 20;
    var output;
    while (x < lines) {
        while( y < lines*2){
            output = ("<span id='x" + x + "_" + y + "'>x</span>");
            $('#board').prepend(output);
            y++;
        }
        y = 0;
        x++;
        $('#board').append('<br />');
    }
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<input type='button' value='test' onClick='generate_page()'>
<div id='board'>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

also move the button to the body.

Comment: `<input />` is not required in HTML5, and is not valid in HTML4.

Answer (score 1):

You're opening a DIV tag and closing a SPAN tag in your JavaScript.

Comment: The problem is he forgot an hash `#`.

Comment: Thanks Derek, that was it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are opening a div and closing it with a span, also, you never close the div, and never actually open the span. By the way, utilizing document.createElement("div") is a clean way to do this.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem since the browser will auto-correct it.

Comment: The browser will close it for you and ignore `</span>`. But it doesn't work very well all the time.

Comment: Oh yeah: `document.createElement("div")` ==> `$("<div>")`

Comment: lol im old school... i dunno how many times i start typing new XmlHttpRequest(); :P

Answer (score 1):

you're using jQuery syntax so  you should includ jQuery

like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function generate_page() {
        var x = 0;
        var y = 0;
        var lines = 20;
        var output;
        while (x < lines) {
            while (y < lines * 2) {
                output = ("<div id='x" + x + "_" + y + "'>x</span>");
                $('#board').prepend(output);
                y++;
            }
            y = 0;
            x++;
            $('#board').append('<br />');
        }
    } 
</script></head><body>
<input type='button' value='test' onclick='generate_page()'>
<div id='board'>
</div></body></html>
```

Comment: He did tag it with jquery and he hasnt posted the <html><head> tags to he could have it above.