# centering with margin auto in a jquery widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a jquery widget I am making where I want to center some divs. here is the code I have trying to do it, I cant seem to get it to work.

```
jQuery.fn.nav = function(home, eat, sleep, drink) {
//store the jQuery object(s) for later use
var elements = this;

return this.each(function() {
    var containerElement = this;
    var container = jQuery(this);
    container.css('width', '100%');
    container.css('text-align', 'center');

    var centElement = document.createElement('div');
    var cent = jQuery(centElement);
    cent.css('overflow', 'auto');
    cent.css('width', '275px');
    cent.css('margin-left', 'auto');
    cent.css('margin-right', 'auto');

    if(home == true) {
        var navElement = document.createElement('div');
        var nav = jQuery(navElement);
        nav.addClass('inactive');
        nav.attr('id', 'home');
        cent.append(nav);
    }
    if(eat == true) {
        var navElement = document.createElement('div');
        var nav = jQuery(navElement);
        nav.addClass('inactive');
        nav.attr('id', 'eat');
        cent.append(nav);
    }
    if(drink == true) {
        var navElement = document.createElement('div');
        var nav = jQuery(navElement);
        nav.addClass('inactive');
        nav.attr('id', 'drink');
        cent.append(nav);
    }
    if(sleep == true) {
        var navElement = document.createElement('div');
        var nav = jQuery(navElement);
        nav.addClass('inactive');
        nav.attr('id', 'sleep');
        cent.append(nav);
    }
    container.append(cent);
    //put together the styling used
    var styleText = "#" + containerElement.id + " div {width: 60px; height: 60px; float: left;";
    styleText += " margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 3px;}";
    styleText += "#" + containerElement.id + " div a {display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%;}";
    styleText += "#" + containerElement.id + " #home.inactive {background-image:url(img/inactive_home.png); background-size: cover;}";
    styleText += "#" + containerElement.id + " #eat.inactive {background-image:url(img/inactive_eat.png); background-size: cover;}";
    styleText += "#" + containerElement.id + " #sleep.inactive {background-image:url(img/inactive_sleep.png); background-size: cover;}";
    styleText += "#" + containerElement.id + " #drink.inactive {background-image:url(img/inactive_drink.png); background-size: cover;}";
    styleText += "#" + containerElement.id + " #home.active {background-image:url(img/active_home.png); background-size: cover;}";
    styleText += "#" + containerElement.id + " #eat.active {background-image:url(img/active_eat.png); background-size: cover;}";
    styleText += "#" + containerElement.id + " #sleep.active {background-image:url(img/active_sleep.png); background-size: cover;}";
    styleText += "#" + containerElement.id + " #drink.active {background-image:url(img/active_drink.png); background-size: cover;}";
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.innerHTML = styleText;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
});
}
```

Let me explain a little more since people seem to not like my question. I have always used 'margin: 0 auto' to center a div, in fact that is how I am centering the body of the page linked below (easyuniv.com/staging). I have this javascript function that creates my navigation inside of the div it is called on. The variable container is the div that it is called on, and I set its width to 100% and then append a div(called cent) into it, which has margin-left and margin-right auto.

For some reason I can't get this to center my div and am trying to figure out why not.

Thanks for any help

Comment: *I guess you haven't been taught English, if so, I forgive you.* `:P` You could have concentrated on the specific code alone, instead of posting the whole code!

Comment: And yah, why do you need jQuery to center them? Cant you just use CSS? Moreover, where is the CSS and HTML? Any preview? Any [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: this function is just called on the jQuery object of a div, and then creates this section. Due to the nature of what im doing i need the jQuery to apply the css. As far as posting too much code, sorry, didn't want to leave anything out.

Comment: Okay, is there anywhere we can see the preview? Or access the site? Can you make us a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: you should probably take a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220603/is-there-a-best-practice-for-generating-html-with-javascript) as well

Comment: OKay, there's something like many numbers. What am I supposed to do? And the whole content is appearing centred.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I think the OP wants the 4 divs (home,eat, drink and sleep) to be centered

Comment: im trying to get the four nav buttons (home, eat, sleep, drink) to be centered. The code above generates that part of the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Okay, got your issue. Use this CSS:

```
#hesd div {margin: 25px auto 10px; float: none;}
```

#### Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: i ended up figuring out my problem, i needed to scope in one further div in one spot that effectively did what you said to add here, thanks for your help! and sorry for the poorly worded question

Answer (score 1):

Change your `var styleText` with the following style

```
    var styleText = "#" + containerElement.id + " div {width: 60px; height: 60px;";
    styleText += " margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 3px;}";
    styleText += "#" + containerElement.id + " div a {display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%;}";
    styleText += "#" + containerElement.id + " #home.inactive {background-image:url(img/inactive_home.png); background-size: cover;float:left;}";
    styleText += "#" + containerElement.id + " #eat.inactive {background-image:url(img/inactive_eat.png); background-size: cover;float:left;}";
    styleText += "#" + containerElement.id + " #sleep.inactive {background-image:url(img/inactive_sleep.png); background-size: cover;float:left;}";
    styleText += "#" + containerElement.id + " #drink.inactive {background-image:url(img/inactive_drink.png); background-size: cover;float:left;}";
    styleText += "#" + containerElement.id + " #home.active {background-image:url(img/active_home.png); background-size: cover;float:left;}";
    styleText += "#" + containerElement.id + " #eat.active {background-image:url(img/active_eat.png); background-size: cover;float:left;}";
    styleText += "#" + containerElement.id + " #sleep.active {background-image:url(img/active_sleep.png); background-size: cover;float:left;}";
    styleText += "#" + containerElement.id + " #drink.active {background-image:url(img/active_drink.png); background-size: cover;float:left;}";
```

Hope this will help