# convert html to html string in JS file

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create some html via JS, therefore I need to write the html inside the JS file like:

```
function createHtmlSection() {
    return "<li class=\"chapter up-wrapper-btn\">" +
        "<div>" +
        "<button><i class=\"fa fa-plus\" onclick=\"addSection('up',this)\"></i></button>" +
        "<label contenteditable=\"true\">section 1</label>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</li>";
}
```

is there a tool or some shortcut to create this type of html string?

I mean, in this case I was needed to type all this html by hand. with `+` and needed to add `"` sign.

Something that can convert this:

```
<li class="chapter up-wrapper-btn">
    <div>
       <button><i class="fa fa-plus" onclick="addSection('up',this)"></i></button>
        <label contenteditable="true">section 1</label>
     </div>
</li>
```

to the first string that I was needed to type by hand

Comment: From where will your script get the HTML you want to convert into a string ?

Comment: This post should answer your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220603/is-there-a-best-practice-for-generating-html-with-javascript

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (note the back-ticks). The literal supports multiline, and you won't need to escape the quotes (you'll need to escape back-ticks).

```
`<li class="chapter up-wrapper-btn">
    <div>
       <button><i class="fa fa-plus" onclick="addSection('up',this)"></i></button>
        <label contenteditable="true">section 1</label>
     </div>
</li>`
```

Example:

```js
function createHtmlSection() {
  return `
    <li class="chapter up-wrapper-btn">
        <div>
           <button><i class="fa fa-plus" onclick="addSection('up',this)"></i></button>
            <label contenteditable="true">section 1</label>
         </div>
    </li>
  `;
}


document.querySelector('#root')
  .innerHTML = createHtmlSection();
```

```html
<ul id="root"></ul>
```

You can also pass parameters to the function, and insert them to the string using [expression interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Expression_interpolation):

```js
function createHtmlSection(label) {
  return `
    <li class="chapter up-wrapper-btn">
        <div>
           <button><i class="fa fa-plus" onclick="addSection('up',this)"></i></button>
            <label contenteditable="true">${label}</label>
         </div>
    </li>
  `;
}


document.querySelector('#root')
  .innerHTML = createHtmlSection('!!! section !!!');
```

```html
<ul id="root"></ul>
```

Comment: Good Answer, but it's important to say that this is ES6-Syntax which isn't supported by all browsers. So you would need something like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to compile your code to browser-compatible JavaScript (ES5).

Comment: This is why I add a link to MDN. They have a compatibility table at the bottom. Currently the only browser that doesn't support template literals is IE.

Answer (score 3):

update your JS file to:

```
function createHtmlSection() {
    return `
             <li class="chapter up-wrapper-btn">
                <div>
                  <button>
                     <i class="fa fa-plus" onclick="addSection('up',this)"></i> 
                  </button>
                  <label contenteditable="true">section 1</label>
               </div>
             </li>
          `
}
```

Read this link for more information:
[template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use ' (one quote) so you dont have to put / front every "

Answer (score 1):

Just use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (not a single quote "'" but the back-tick "`") like this:

```js
// JavaScript

document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = `<li class="chapter up-wrapper-btn">
    <div>
       <button><i class="fa fa-plus" onclick="addSection('up',this)"></i></button>
        <label contenteditable="true">section 1</label>
     </div>
</li>`
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<div id="a"></div>
```

> Template literals are string literals allowing embedded expressions.
>   You can use multi-line strings and string interpolation features with
>   them. They were called "template strings" in prior editions of the
>   ES2015 specification.
>
> Via - [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method is to use single quotes and escape the newline character.

Something like this:

```js
function createHtmlSection() {
    return '<li class="chapter up-wrapper-btn">\
        <div>\
            <button><i class="fa fa-plus" onclick="addSection(\'up\',this)"></i></button>\
            <label contenteditable="true">section 1</label>\
        </div>\
    </li>';
}

console.log(createHtmlSection());
```

Swapping to single quotes saves you from escaping the double quotes in the HTML, but you still need to quote the single quotes.

---

Another alternative is to use an array and `.join('')` it:

```js
function createHtmlSection() {
    return [
 '<li class="chapter up-wrapper-btn">',
            '<div>',
                '<button><i class="fa fa-plus" onclick="addSection(\'up\',this)"></i></button>',
                '<label contenteditable="true">section 1</label>',
            '</div>',
        '</li>'
    ].join('');
}

console.log(createHtmlSection());
```

This allows you to easily add/edit/delete parts of the code later on.

---

Both of these options are for ES5 or older.

For modern browser, **please** use [the ES6 version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59239450/2729937) provided by [Ori Drori](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5157454/ori-drori).